# Terraform won't upgrade provider

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I am trying to upgrade the terraform kubernetes provider to the [latest version 2.7.1](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/releases). The following is an excerpt from the current terraform configuration:

```
terraform {
    required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
    required_providers {
        aws = {
            source = "hashicorp/aws"
            version = "3.60.0"
        }
        kubernetes = {
            source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
            version = "2.5.0" # Trying to change this...
        }
        helm = {
            source = "hashicorp/helm"
            version = "2.3.0"
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Following [these instructions](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/init#plugin-installation) I tried:

1. to change the version to `>= 2.5.0`;
2. to change the version to `2.7.1` (or even `2.5.1`, just for the test);

and run `terraform init -upgrade`. Unfortunately, attempt (1) has no effect, and (2) gives an error:

```
Upgrading modules...
[...]

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/kubernetes versions matching "2.5.0, >= 2.5.1"...
- Finding hashicorp/helm versions matching ">= 2.3.0, 2.3.0"...
[...]
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/helm v2.3.0
[...]
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/kubernetes: no available releases match the given constraints 2.5.0, >= 2.5.1
```

I tried to init a new project (in an empty directory) with the above, and it correctly installs version `2.7.1`, therefore I presume the problem is with the pre-existing terraform state. How can I upgrade the provider?

Comment: Do you have any modules declared in your config?

Comment: According to the message `Upgrading modules...` I think you have a module that uses an old provider that isn't compatible with this k8s provider version. You can try upgrading the other ones first.

Comment: You can use the `terraform providers` command to see where each of the specific version constraints are coming from. `terraform init` combines dependencies together across all modules, but `terraform providers` can show them individually you can get a better understanding of which module might need to be updated to support the new provider version.

Comment: Indeed one of the modules had that strict requirement. I had to update the module first, then I could update the root module, too! Thank you all for the suggestions: if someone is willing to write up an answer with that, I can mark it as accepted to the benefit of future readers.